# How create and open a zip file which is building straight away?

Tags: php, cakephp, zip

I need to be able to open the zip file straight away when we hit the page for download even if the zip file is not created in the server yet.

Is there any way to do this? Because for the moment it takes a lot of time to get the page the start of the download of the zip file.

I'm also getting timeout issue because it takes too much time to build the zip.

```
 $this->loadModel('JobFiles');
    $this->loadComponent('Images');

    $job_nbr = '40819-o';
    $purpose = 'client';

    if (isset($this->request->data['type']) && $this->request->data['type'] != '') {

        $type = $this->request->data['type'];
        $my_files = $this->JobFiles
        ->find()
        ->where([
            'JobFiles.job_number' => $job_nbr,
            'JobFiles.type' => $type,
            'JobFiles.purpose' => $purpose
        ]);

    } else {

        $my_files = $this->JobFiles
        ->find()
        ->where([
            'JobFiles.job_number' => $job_nbr,
            'JobFiles.purpose' => $purpose
        ]);

    }

    $files = array();

    $key = 0;
    foreach( $my_files as $file ){
        // If photo and extension are jpg we provide other files type
        if ($file->type == 'photos' && $file->extension == 'jpg' || $file->extension == 'JPG'):
            $c = $file->ObjectURL;
            $file_headers = @get_headers($c);
            if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
                $exists = false;
            }
            else {
                $files['photos'][$key]['original_file'] = $file->ObjectURL;
                $files['photos'][$key]['name'] = $file->filename;
                $files['photos'][$key]['type'] = $file->type;
                $files['photos'][$key]['id'] = $file->id;
                $key++;
            }
        endif;
        if ($file->type == 'floorplan'):
            $files['floorplan'][$key]['original_file'] = $file->ObjectURL;
            $key++;
        endif;
        if ($file->type == 'video'):
            $files['video'][$key]['original_file'] = $file->ObjectURL;
            $key++;
        endif;
    }

    $zipname = "watherver.zip";
    $zip = new ZipArchive(); 
    $zip_full_path_name = \Cake\Core\Configure::read('pathTo') . '/webroot/img/tmp/zip/' .  $zipname;

    $zip->open($zip_full_path_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
    foreach ($files['photos'] as $file) {
        $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
        $parsed_file = $file['original_file'];
        $download_file = file_get_contents($parsed_file, false,$context);
        $zip->addFromString('photos/original/' . basename($parsed_file), $download_file);
    }

    $zip->close();

    //Set headers
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . $zipName . "'");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zipName));
```

Cheers,

Comment: how do you open something that does not exist?

Comment: We cannot build the zip on the fly and download it from the web browser?

Comment: Because in this case user wait 5min to just start the download of the file.

Comment: The quickest option to get it working is to increase the http connection timeout for that request. The better long term solution is to move the zip creation to a background process using the Events System https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html